# Couldn't compile resource file while making plugin in QGIS in mac. Pyrcc5 is not in your path error

Tags: qgis, pyrcc

I was trying to create a plugin in QGIS. I was following [this](http://www.qgistutorials.com/ko/docs/3/building_a_python_plugin.html).

While trying to compile my resource file. I got *pyrcc5 is not in your path---unable to compile your resource file(s)* error.

I searched everywhere but there were no valid solutions for mac.

I even tried chatGPT but it didn't work.

chatGPT gave me this:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
export PATH="/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
which pyrcc5
```

Comment: "I even tried ChatGPT". Heh. The [Stochastic Parrot](https://irisvanrooijcogsci.com/2023/01/14/stop-feeding-the-hype-and-start-resisting/) strikes again.

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install pyqt@5
```

Fixes the issue.

```
install pyqt
```

Installs pyqt@6 which cannot compile the resource file.